# SAML user provisioning

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I've setup an IdP and a first SP to start using SSO across our products. I'm new to SAML and I'm wondering when it comes to user provisioning, that is whether the user exists in the IdP database or not, **is it the responsibility of the IdP ?** **Does SAML support the creation of users with the IdP** in case they don't exist or is it a pre-requisite that they are already there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function of an IDP (and more correctly an STS) is to authenticate and generate signed tokens.

What you are referring to is an Identity Manager which provisions users into a repository and handles password self-service etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use so called 'auto federation' on the SP side. This would create a 'user profile' on the SP side based on the attribute statements sent by the IdP in the SAML assertion. However the SP must support this.

Potentially you had this in mind when saying

> Does SAML support the creation of users with the IdP

Comment: But only if they already exist on the IdP side, that was my question.